# Newtonsoft cannnot deserialize an empty F# sequence?

Tags: f#, json.net

Using Newtonsoft.Json, latest version (=6.0.6) I get the following error:

`` Cannot create and populate list type         Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers+EmptyEnumerable`1[System.String] ``

However in a [post](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2014/04/30/json-net-6-0-release-3-serialize-all-the-f) it was announced that Newtonsoft.Json would fully support Fsharp types?

When I change the offending type to a regular array, everything works fine.

The code:

```
type Prescription () = 
    member val Id = "" with get, set
    member val Status = new PrescriptionStatus() with get, set
    member val Prescriber = new Prescriber() with get, set
    member val Indications = [||] : string[] with get, set
```

When I change Indications to be:

```
    member val Indications = Seq.empty : string seq with get, set
```

I run into the error.

Also, when I initialise what is in fact an enumerable as an array, it cannot be constructed:

```
member val Indications : string seq = [||] |> Array.toSeq with get, set
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the answer is, Newtonsoft.Json doesn't fully support F# types.

But F# doesn't make supporting them particularly easy. For instance, an empty seq defined with `Seq.empty` is not just an `IEnumerable<T>`, it's a particular enumerable implementation `EmptyEnumerable<T>`, and this seems to throw off serialization - most likely because there's no appropriate constructor on it. From the post you linked to:

> To all future creators of immutable .NET collections: If your collection of T has a constructor that takes IEnumerable then Json.NET will automatically work when deserializing to your collection, otherwise you're all out of luck.

If you initialize your seq like this instead, perhaps the behaviour will be different:

```
member val Indications = Seq.ofArray [||] : string seq with get, set
```

But that's splitting hairs, the actual answer here is simple - don't serialize seqs. Just use concrete, well-behaved types like arrays. The simpler the type, the less likely it is to give you headaches when doing serialization or interop.

Comment: Thanks, I already did try that, however that didn't work. So, I guess this is just not implemented. Have to switch back to just an array.

Answer (score 2):

Setting `JsonSerializerSettings.ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace` will fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

I liked the notion of using simple types like arrays, only I wanted to use the same DTOs also for mapping to IQueryable in Linq queries. So, in that respect, arrays were not an option.

Luckily with some testing, it was simple:

```
#load ".\Scripts\load-project.fsx"

#time

open System
open System.Collections.Generic

open Newtonsoft.Json

[<CLIMutable>]
type Test1 =
    {
        Strings : string seq
    }

type Test2 () =
    member val Strings = Seq.empty : IEnumerable<string> with get, set

type Test3 () =
    member val Strings = Seq.empty : String seq with get, set

type Test4 () =
    member val Strings : IEnumerable<string> = Seq.empty : IEnumerable<string> with get, set

type Test5 () =
    member val Strings : IEnumerable<string> = [] |> List.toSeq : IEnumerable<string> with get, set

type Test6 () =
    member val Strings = [] |> List.toSeq : string seq with get, set

let test1 = { Strings = Seq.empty }
let test2 = new Test2 ()
let test3 = new Test3 () 
let test4 = new Test4 () 
let test5 = new Test5 () 
let test6 = new Test6 () 

let json1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test1)
let json2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test2)
let json3 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test3)
let json4 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test4)
let json5 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test5)
let json6 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test6)

let deserialized1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test1>(json1) // Fails
let deserialized2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test2>(json2) // Fails
let deserialized3 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test3>(json3) // Fails
let deserialized4 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test4>(json4) // Fails
let deserialized5 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test5>(json5) // Passes
let deserialized6 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test5>(json6) // Passes
```

So, as long as you construct your sequence using a type that has a recognisable constructor, for example a list, the object can be deserialised. Strangely enough, initializing the sequence as an array and then converting it to a sequence, like with the list to sequence example (which passes), fails.